# SQL Server convert flat table to attribute based structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a flat table of data imported from an Excel spreadsheet....

```
tbl_ProductsImport
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductId | Name | Description | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | Attribute4 etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       P1     Some desc..   x                         x            x
12346       P2     Some desc..                x            
12347       P3     Some desc..   x            x            x            x
12348       P4     Some desc..   x                                      x
```

I want to convert that to the following table structure...

```
tbl_Products
------------------------------
ProductId (pk) | Name | Description

tbl_Attributes
----------------------------------------------
AttributeId (pk) | Name (derrived from column)

tbl_ProductAttributes
----------------------
ProductId (fk) | AttributeId (fk)
```

So I ask, how would I go about writing a statement to do this?

Edit: This will be part of a scheduled data import job that truncates all of the existing data before executing.

Comment: Is there _some_ 'default' set of attributes?  What are the attributes?  Especially as they appear to be pretty much booleans (unless you've left something off in `productAttributes`)?  Otherwise, you're headed towards an EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) table, which is generally considered an SQL Anti-pattern.  Among other things, they're usually difficult to query efficiently.  Also, don't prefix tables with `tbl_` - among other things, it looks really weird if you change your actual schema, but recreate it as a view for 'legacy' applications.

Comment: The value of the attributes doesn't matter as I just need to assign them so a particular product when the value of that field is say "x". Why is an EAV generally consdiered an SQL anti-pattern? How else could I go about doing this in a way that would allow the attributes to change from import to import without having to strongly type and reengineer my consuming application every time?

Comment: _How_ are the values changing between imports (presumed from Excel)?  Depending on how that's happening, you could be best served by changing your underlying schema _anyways_.  Or, it may indicate some other problem (say, somebody accidently formats a column wrong).  EAVs are often considered anti-patterns because they are sometimes implemented for something that really should be a single row (Say, all attributes are required).  Most of the time, EAVs have to be pivoted in order to be intelligently queried, and you lose (native) type-safety (because everything is stored as strings).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  Would this work?  Nasty nasty dynamic SQL, but sometimes it's gotta be done.

```
INSERT  tbl_Products
SELECT  ProductId, Name, Description
FROM    tbl_ProductsImport

INSERT  tbl_Attributes (Name)
SELECT  c.name
FROM    sys.sysobjects o
JOIN    sys.syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id
WHERE   o.name = 'tbl_ProductsImport'
AND     c.name LIKE 'Attribute%'

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @DynamicSQL = ''

DECLARE @AttributeId INT
DECLARE @AttributeName NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @AttributeId = MIN(AttributeId)
FROM    tbl_Attributes

WHILE (@AttributeId <= (SELECT MAX(AttributeId) FROM tbl_Attributes))
BEGIN
    SELECT  @AttributeName = Name
    FROM    dbo.tbl_Attributes
    WHERE   AttributeId = @AttributeId

    SELECT  @DynamicSQL =
    'INSERT tbl_ProductAttributes
    SELECT  ProductId, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @AttributeId) + '
    FROM    tbl_ProductsImport
    WHERE   ' + @AttributeName + ' = 1'

    EXEC    (@DynamicSQL)

    SET @AttributeId = @AttributeId + 1
END
```

This assumes the values for Attributes in tbl_ProductsImport are BITs.  Haven't tried it so might be an uber-fail.

Jim